# Export All emails + Attachments in a Gmail (G-Suite) account to a folder structure

Tags: gmail, export

I Have 6 G-Suite email accounts I need to remove however some of my staff still requires the contents of those Gmail accounts as they span 3-6 years and have a lot of historical data.  I am looking for a way to Export the emails into a drive like structure, or individual files (with attachments) so they can be searched in Drive.

Are there any tools that can do this? A few of these email drives have upwards of 20gb of email.

Answer (score 1):

Google provides an data export function with several different options, both for the format and where to export to. You can read more about the tool [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190?hl=en).

Comment: Google downloads it as an Mbox format, I haven't seen any type of other options.

Answer (score 0):

- you can download all your data here: **[https://takeout.google.com/](https://takeout.google.com/?hl=en-GB&utm_source=google-account&utm_medium=web)**

[image: 0]

Comment: This is an MBOX format, something that isn't compatible by browsing it with a file explorer or on google drive. THat's what I'm after.